# solr does not select document where field has value "null"

Tags: solr

I have a document that has the value `"null"` for the field `image`.
*select?q=signature%3A8e237da66f894cff8b1b6a94a76807a9&wt=json&indent=true*

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "signature:8e237da66f894cff8b1b6a94a76807a9",
      "_": "1417003669026",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "signature": "8e237da66f894cff8b1b6a94a76807a9",
        "clicks": 0,
        "content": "foo",
        "customer_id": 1,
        "firstseen": "2014-11-19T15:10:39Z",
        "image": "null", // <--------------------------
        "impressions": 165,
        "language": "en",
        "lastupdate": "2014-11-26T11:45:01Z",
        "media_id": 3,
        "title": "bar",
        "url": "http://www.foobar.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I am not able to find this document when searching for documents where `image:null`.
*select?q=image%3Anull&wt=json&indent=true*

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 6,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "image:null",
      "_": "1417008837414",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
```

Could you explain what is wrong with the query and why the document is not returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the `schema.xml` to see if the field is being indexed.

The field `image` was not being indexed and could not be searched on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search with null, if you are looking for item with no image field, use

```
-image:*
```

If u have in ur index null as a value, you have to check u field type. It has to be a string. It is easy to detect this problem by trying

```
image:*null*
```

Comment: In the first solr response null is surrounded by quotes: `"image": "null"`. Does this not mean that the value `"null"` is a string?

Comment: No, double quotes mean exact search [A Phrase is a group of words surrounded by double quotes such as "hello dolly"]. Did you try with double wildcard? What is the type of the field in ur schema?